# Ionic3 - fastest way to syncronize big JSON file data with Sqlite

Tags: json, angular, sqlite, cordova, ionic5

Good afternoon, I am creating an application in ionic using angular where currently it handles two connection modes: connected if the user has internet access and disconnected if they do not have it

Currently I have a feature and it is that the user has the possibility to sync data and apply in SQLite

like this JSON (to syncronize)

```
{
   countries: [/* 200+ records */],
   vaccine: [/* 3000+ records */],
   ... other 20 keys
}
```

and the SQLite structure(mobile) has a table per key like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countries(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    code TEXT NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NULL,
    --- other columns
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vaccine(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NULL,
    --- other columns
);
```

How can I execute the synchronization process without executing sql per cycle? but validating that if the row exists, update it

```ts
public descargar(clave): void {
  this.descargarParametricas().subscribe(
    parametros => {
      // make process by key
      Object.keys(parametros).forEach(
        index => this.descargarParametrica(index, parametros[index]) : void(0)
      );
    }
  );
}

public descargarParametrica( key: string, parametros: any[] ){
  parametros.forEach( item => {
    const headers = Object.keys(item);
    const rows = Object.values(item).map( item => item === '' ? 'NULL' : item );
    const sqlQuery = `INSERT INTO ${key}(${headers.join()}) VALUES (${rows.join()});`;
    // execute query per loop is too slow, only countries data(200 records) affect performance and stop
    this.datalayer.execute(sqlQuery);
  })
}
```

**this.descargarParametricas()** return a JSON 40kb size, the problem is that the insertion process must be done by the key of the json **and update if the row exist,** actually have a performance issues because the insertion/update process execute row per row

thanks for all

Comment: You can send the datetime in the request to your backend to fetch the data only which are updated or inserted after the specified date. It can reduce the data which need to update or insert in the mobile app side.